# Vim % matching when match is also included in quoted text

Tags: perl, vim, match, quote

I've searched the Vim Tips Wiki, asked on IRC, now you:

Is there a Vim plugin that will change % matching behavior to skip quoted or escaped matches?

Given:

```
1  var1{
2     ...
3    { Target = 'blah blah.*}',
4     ...
5    }
6    ...
7    $fem = \};
8  }
```

With the cursor on the { in line 1 % would then take you to line 8 - skipping the quoted } in line 3 and the escaped } in line 7.

The intent is to navigate through Data::Dumper dumps with embedded quoted code fragments.

The matchit plugin, to my reading of the docs, does not handle this case.

Cluestick pointer preferred.

Answer (score 2):

from :h %

```
When 'cpoptions' contains "M" |cpo-M| backslashes           
    before parens and braces are ignored.  Without "M" the          
number of backslashes matters: an even number doesn't 
match with an odd number.  Thus in "( \) )" and "\( ( \)" the first and last parenthesis match.
```

M option for cpo:

```
M   

When excluded, "%" matching will take backslashes into          
account.  Thus in "( \( )" and "\( ( \)" the outer          
parenthesis match.  When included "%" ignores           
backslashes, which is Vi compatible.
```

Comment: That does address the \} case.

However the quoted case, line 3 in the example, is still a problem.

Comment: In `:h %` it is mentioned that when `'cpoption'` flag `%` (`cpo-%`) is not present then `%` will skip parens inside double quotes. But it also adds the following: `Note that this works fine for C, but not for Perl, where single quotes are used for strings.`. Changing single quotes to double quotes on your example with `:set cpo-=%` seems to work fine. So it seems that it is not possible to solve the problem directly with Vim options. You will probably be able to solve it by extending `%` behavior with matchit plugin (`:h matchit`), which is bundled with Vim.